# Putting and getting DoubleArray values between Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-bundle

I have an activity where the values are retrieved from the `ResultSet` and I store them in an array as:

```
flat[i] = rs.getDouble(3);
flng[i] = rs.getDouble(4);
i++;
Intent i = new Intent(MapID.this, map.class);
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putDoubleArray("Lat", flat);
bundle.putDoubleArray("Long", flng);
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
```

On the other class I get the values by:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
flat = bundle.getDoubleArray("Lat");
```

I want to convert the values to String something like:

```
String xx = new Double(flat).toString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [String.valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-double-) on each element of your array and store it to another `String` array like this:

```
double[] flat = bundle.getDoubleArray("Lat");
String[] flatAsStrings = new String[flat.length];

for (int i = 0; i < flat.length; i++) {
    flatAsStrings[i] = String.valueOf(flat[i]);
}
```

To simply print these `float` values without converting it to Strings, you can do it like this:

```
double[] flat = bundle.getDoubleArray("Lat");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(flat));
```

Will print something like (depends on your input):

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
```

Comment: yes Can you please explain that i want the values from the array as one after one and to store it in separate strings

Comment: I have getting a nullpointer Exception in resultset any idea? 

`while(rs.next())
{            flat[i]=rs.getDouble(3);      flng[i]=rs.getDouble(4);

i++;
}`   
Query Looks correct unless I tried as Array

Comment: What do you mean with **in** ResultSet? Can't you access `rs.next()`? Or are you not able to store the result of `rs.getDouble(x)` to the variable? How do you define your Arrays `flat` and `flng`?

Comment: Yes.>I cant able to store the `resultset` values
I declare it as `double[] flat;`
 `double[] flng;`

Comment: So you didn't initialize them! You have to write something like `double[] flat = new double[42];` to initialize the array with 42 elements. I don't know, if you know, how many elements you will get. A `List` could be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the + operator is defined for primitives. You can simply do something like `String xx = "" + myDouble;`

Although it is recommended to use the String methods like this : `String xx = String.valueOf(myDouble);`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what did you want that convert the values to String. If you want to convert single double number to String, you can use this:

```
String.valueOf(double);
```

But I think you need to changed all numbers of the double array to String, you may use this:

```
Arrays.toString(double[]);
```

If you need to put the all result's data to bundle, you may use this:

```
Bundle.putSparseParcelableArray(String key, SparseArray<? extends Parcelable> value);
```

SparseArray is very useful in android. It likes java.util.Map, but the key must be integer.